# Delete item of database via ListView and id

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have an android app with a `ListView` and data of my local `sql` database.
Now I would like to delete an item from my database with the ID.

I would like to make a long press on any row, and this should delete the item.

```
 ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// DELETE ACTION
}
```

But how can I get the item ID of my Database?
At the moment I save with the query the ID in a hidden `TextView` and get this ID via `findviewbyid()`.

But is this the correct way?

Adapter:

```
public class DatabaseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> databaseList;


public DatabaseListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> list) {
    this.context = context;
    databaseList = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return databaseList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return databaseList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    DatabaseListItems databaseListItems = databaseList.get(position);


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_item, null);

    }

    TextView tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewID);
    tvID.setText(databaseListItems.getID());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your Adapter implement onItemLongClickListener.

```
public class DatabaseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

...

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    long itemID = databaseList.get(position).getID();

    //Perform delete

    return true;
}
```

So you can access the ID of your item the same way like you do it in getView() method.

Answer (score 0):

Create one model class with id and title and sotre that in listview. For ex.

```
public class Data{
 private int id;
 private String title;

 public Data(int id,String title){
     this.id = id;
     this.title = title;

 }
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

Where you fill your listview do this

```
list.add(new Data(1,"xyz"))
```

so inside click event

```
ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   int id  = list.get(posttion).getId(); //you can get id like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you are using `CursorAdapter` for your `ListView`. If so, I suggest you to get the id from `Cursor` object in `bindView()`. Use ViewHolder pattern to attach some information to your `ListView` row.

```
class ViewHolder{
TextView text;
ImageView image;
...
long id;}
```

Add long id to it and retrieve it on long click.

Answer (score 0):

basically your adapter should have data in that data should be the the `id` of the Item to delete, so we will assume each adapter has a and an arraylist named `dataArrayList` containing your adapter data, when we click that button we delete the item in db, so it would look like:

```
 deletebtn.setOnItemLongClickListener(->(position){

   Contact mContact = dataArrayList.get(position).getContact();
   deleteContact(mContact);

 //adapter this then we can remove the listview adapter row whose data
 //we just deleted in the db
    arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
    arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDatasetChange();
  //finally we want to remove the arraylist data too from it

  dataArrayList.remove(position);
}


//Our Delete method in our database class

public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create POJO class of item or id like

```
class info{
    private String item;
    private int id;
    info(String item,int id){
        this.item = item;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public setItem(String item){
        this.item=item;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public String getItem(){
        return item;
    } 
}
```

and Store object into ArrayList so you can get ID of specific item with position

```
ArrayList.get(position).getId();
ArrayList.remove(position);
notifyDatasetChange();
```

or

Simple you create two ArrayList like

```
ArrayList<String> mItem = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> mId = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then you can get id of specific position and remove both from arraylist

```
mId.get(position);
mId.remove(position);
mItem.remove(position);
notifyDatasetChange();
```